# Can SCN file be too big?

Tags: ios, xcode, scenekit, augmented-reality

I’m developing an app for which I need to load a 3D object into the augmented world. I have managed to get a 3D model which I would like to use. The file was originally in a solidworks file format. I used the website I downloaded the 3D file from to convert the part I needed into an .stl file. I then used sketch up to convert this to a dae file. Now the issue is that the resulting file is 917mb big. When I move this into my Xcode project it hangs for ages and sometimes even tells me that my system as run out of application memory. To fix this I used Xcode to convert the .dae file into a .scn file. This has reduced the file size to 317mb but now the issue is that once I load it into my scene to show in the augmented world as soon as the camera sees the model the whole application freezes. I turned the statistics on and set the max frame rate to 120(I have an iPad Pro) and as soon as the object is seen the frame rates drop to 19fps. Does anybody know if there is something I can do to get my object to augment smoothly and stop the application from freezing. I don’t know what part of my application code I should put up so if you need anything to help with answering my question let me know and I will post the code which is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unfortunate side effect of the exactitude and detail possible in CAD and NURBS based 3D design applications. Solidworks and Rhino are probably the two most famous for the ENORMOUS number of triangles they generate in their efforts to export accurate "models".

And yes, you are right, the size of the resultant geometry is the problem. But no amount of pruning and optimising of the output geometry will get you good results.

Gaming based models are made, from the ground up, in gaming focused geometry, with different creation techniques designed to optimise the manner in which the geometry exists, from the beginning.

Efforts to smooth and add detail to a base geometry then provide the intricacies and nuances above these primitive geometries.

Whatever you're needing to present, you're going to need to find COLLADA files that have been modelled in this way, or 3ds files made by someone familiar with the optimisations required for game engines and live rendering environments.

Those files from SolidWorks, and all optimisations that operate on them, target offline rendering solutions and engineering requirements/considerations, not gaming needs.

Sorry to be the bringer of bad news. I hope you can get a refund on the model, or use it as a guide for someone to help you make a game model of it.

Comment: Hi Confused (I was confused lol). Thank you very much for your detailed answer. You are right in saying that solid works generates a ton of triangles and other things that are not needed for this application. Looking through the nodes of the object many of them are just blank or so small they dont make a difference in the appearance of the model in xcode but add to the overall size of the model. Luckily I have found another model which is small enough that Xcode and my iPad can handle without losing frames. Thanks once again for your answer :)